# Can't get access to my SQL Server on localhost

Tags: sql-server, login

Recently I have been having problems accessing `local` connection in my SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

I am connected to a network, and my account has administrator rights on all the computers. When I connect to SSMS\local, the only Logins available are BUILTIN\USERS and sa. I can't change this or reset the passwords because I don't have access.

I find this strange because Administrator group should be higher than Users group. Even if I log off and connect to the computer locally as Administrator I still have problems.

I've tried everything, the only thing that works is to change startup parameters in Configuration Manager and include `-m`. But if I add a new Login, it doesn't persist if I remove `-m` again.

Someone please help me!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you're relying on the builtin "Administrators" group membership to grant "sa" rights to a use be sure you're running SQL Management Studio elevated, otherwise your user isn't an "Administrator" and, ergo, won't have "sa" rights either.

Comment: nope..I'm running as administrator.

Comment: Hmm... Well, it was worth a shot.